# how to assign a top-level const from a promise when top-level await is not available

Tags: javascript, constants, es6-promise

I'm trying to assign a `const` at the top-level, where the value needs to come from an asynchronous function.   However the version of nodejs on the production server I am using is not new enough to support await, so I can't do something like this:

```
const value = await f(x)
```

I can't declare the variable inside something like `then` because it isn't scoped at the top level, so something like this *won't work*:

```
f(x).then(val=>{const value=val}) // no top-level const value afterwards
```

How can I initialize the `const` properly in this environment?

If it helps, for this particular case the function actually does return synchronously for the particular value I am passing it, but since it's defined as async and sometimes returns asynchronously it's actually returning a Promise all the time.

As a (horrible) workaround, I considered simply assigning the `const` to the Promise and then extract the value whenever I needed it using `.then()`.  However, despite the Promise being resolved this seems to always cause the value to be extracted asychronously, which means it won't work as when I need the value I need it right at that point and not after the current function completes or whenever.

Comment: You can't initialize a const like this. Make it an ordinary variable and assign it in `.then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define you var with "let" instead of const, then assign the value in the "then".

```
let value;
f(x).then(val => value = val)
```

Maybe you have a better way to do this, but with the contexte we have, I would do it this way.

Comment: That works to assign, but it seems that it's still possible to assign value again elsewhere, unlike with `const`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But you can't declare a const and then assign it. You just can't do what you want to achieve, unfortunately. If you absolutely want to use const, you'll have to refactor your code so your variable become available to the rest of your code, or you need to update nodeJS to be able to use the await feature.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It may actually be easier to refactor the code path so that i don't go through the async function for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to move all code that needs the value of that const inside a function. Either move it in a (large) `then` callback, or create an `async` function wrapper.

So let's say your code now looks like this:

```
async function f(x) {
    // ....
    return //...
}

function g(value) {
    // something 
}

const value = await f(x);

// ...

g(value);

// ...

console.log(value);

// ...
```

Then change that to:

```
(async function main() {
    async function f(x) {
        // ....
        return // ...
    }
    
    function g(value) {
        // something 
    }
    
    const value = await f(x);
    
    // ...
    
    g(value);
    
    // ...
    
    console.log(value);
    
    // ...

})(); // Execute main
```

OK, it is not absolutely necessary to move *everything* in it, but this just shows how you *can* solve your problem.